TikZ - How to place a label on a PS image using PS coordinates
I would like to place a label on PS image as in:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (image) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7, trim=1cm 1cm 0 0]{grandcanyon}};
    \node at (image.west) {$y$};
    \node at (image.south) {$x$};
    \node [black, font=\bfseries] at (0.59,0.45) {$\Gamma$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

but instead of using the canvas coordinates, use the PS points.
How can one change the coordinate system to take into account the size of the image?

The image above (/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphicxbox/examples/graphics/grandcanyon.eps) has
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 150 113

and I would like to access a particular point within those coordinates.

does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/ answer your question?

@cfr It 'almost' does. The use of [scope] in @caramdir answer set the use of [0-1]-percent coodinates to access any point. I am looking for the use of raw PS points, which will certainly require TikZ to recognize the the BoundingBox of the image.

you could set x and y to one ps point each either for the picture or for the scope. generally, relative coordinates are easier but, if you know positions in some other system already, you can just tell tikz to use that system. by default x and y are 1cm each, but they can be anything you like so long as you don't exceed tex's limits. which engine are you using?

@cfr The devil is in the details. I have tried using coordinates under scope to set the PS points coordinates with someting like:
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}] coordinates { (0, 0) (364, 272) };
but I am having problems using the new coordinates and passing the BoundingBox values to TikZ.

you need e.g. x=1pt,y=1pt if you want to use those as coordinates.

You can ask pgf/tikz to use whatever values you prefer for x and y. If you want to have coordinates in points, you can say x=1pt,y=1pt or whatever. (Obviously, if you scale the image, you may want x=0.7pt,y=0.7pt, for example.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\node [inner sep=0pt]  (image) {\includegraphics{Jack-spade-color}};
\begin{scope}[shift=(image.south west)]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) rectangle (121,186);
\node at (image.west) {$y$};
\node at (image.south) {$x$};
\node [black, font=\bfseries] at (121,186) {$\Gamma$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I used an image from pst-poker because it is available out-of-the-box in both EPS and PDF formats. The size is roughly 121 by 186 points.


Nice! Is it possible to define the units (that will be new units) after the loading of the image by \includegraphics? Does TikZ have any ways to recognize the size of the image?

@TeXApprentice sorry, but I don't understand. you can set x and y in a scope. I didn't bother because there was no reason to do so here. You can measure things, obviously. depending on your engine, you can even get that information direct from the backend, though wrapping it is more flexible. it is easier to measure things outside tikzpicture, but it is possible to do it inside, too. you could just get the coordinates of the node, if the image is already placed. but I don't see what that has to do with your original question which was about using absolute dimensions as coordinates.

I am not sure I undertand a tiny bit of what you describe. I am still trying to read the manuals and understand all issues related to setting a particular unit for the axis, but from experimenting with scope I can see that TikZ does understand where the picture starts and ends -- even after scalling by includegraphics -- which is the issue here. If you change the scale you have to chage all labels. I am trying to make it work, with my example (scale=0.7) and have not been able to.

@TeXApprentice you asked how to use an absolute point value for coordinates. that means the coordinates won't change if you scale or trim the picture. if you want coordinates which are relative to the size of the picture, then you don't want to use points or any other independent measure. that's the attraction of the posts I linked: the coordinates adapt perfectly to the size of the included image. but that was not what you said you wanted. if you just want to scale them, use x=0.7pt,y=0.7pt for scale=0.7. then they should be proportional.
